# Angular 2: Router Tree is not load correctly in complex module architecture

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, router

I have a complex module architecture to separate domains in my Angular2 application.
Well, I follow a Routing architecure in tour of heroes tutorial wich each module has the own app-routing.module to declare the routes:

- app.module.ts (app-routing.module.ts)

  - features.mdoule.ts (features-routing.module.ts).

    - order.module.ts (order-routing.module.ts).

In my app-routing.module.ts:

```js
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '',  redirectTo: "dashboard", pathMatch: 'full'}, // always first
    { path: '',  loadChildren: () => AuthModule },
    { path: '', loadChildren: () => FeaturesModule, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
    { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent } // always last
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

In my features-routing.module.ts:

```js
const featuresRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'features',  loadChildren: () => OrderModule },
// ... other modules
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(featuresRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class FeaturesRoutingModule {}
```

In my order-routing.module.ts:

```js
const orderRoutes: Routes = [
     { path: 'order',  component: OrderListComponent, data: { info: { title: 'Orders' } } }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(orderRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class OrderRoutingModule {}
```

In case, when I navigate to localhost:3000/features/order is working perfectly, but I can navigate to localhost:3000/order and works too.

How it works the mapping routers in Angular2? There is something wrong in my routing? I need only features/order url works.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

People,

I implemented with successfully in another way, I had to delete imports of my modules in hierarchical modules for Angular-route not join the routes with RootRoutes, this way my components are independents and Lazy Loadeds. Figure out my architecture if someone needs something similar:

app.module.ts

```js
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
        import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
        import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
        import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

        import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
        import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';
        import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';
        import { PartialsModule } from './partials/partials.module';

        import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

        const modules = [
          BrowserModule,
          FormsModule,    
          HttpModule,
          CoreModule,
          AuthModule,
          PartialsModule,
        //  FeaturesModule, I remove the import declaration, only app-   routing.module.ts imports my module for Lazy Loading
          AppRoutingModule
        ];

        const components = [
          AppComponent
        ];

        @NgModule({
          declarations: [
            ...components
          ],
          imports: [
            ...modules
          ],
          providers: [],
          bootstrap: [...components]
        })
        export class AppModule { }
```

In my app-routing-module.ts:

```js
const routePath = 'features';

const routeData = {
    info: { 
        title: 'Features', 
        withoutNavigate: true 
    }
};

const featuresRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: routePath, loadChildren: () => OrderModule , data: routeData}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(featuresRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class FeaturesRoutingModule {}
```

In my order-routing.module.ts:

```js
const orderRoutes: Routes = [
         { path: 'order',  component: OrderListComponent, data: { info: { title: 'Orders' } } }
    ];

    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(orderRoutes)
      ],
      exports: [
        RouterModule
      ]
    })
    export class OrderRoutingModule {}
```

I gonna create a repository with this architecture in github,  I gonna update this comment with the link.

Thanks!